Laravel Passport Authentication; client id and secret passes though Authorization as base64
I am created a Laravel Password Authentication for client_credentials token request api.In that api client_id and client_secret passes as form data. In need to pass it through Authorization Basic <Base64-encoded client_key:client_secret>
Is there any possibility to pass it header in laravel passport.
